# GPS UART NMEA output to iPhone

Tags: uart, gps, iphone

Working on a tracker project. Idea is this:

L80-M39 GPS (UART) -> RF Transceiver <--- distance ---> RF Transceiver (UART) -> ?

On the right-hand side, I am getting location information via UART in NMEA format.

Now I'd like to ideally see the location on an iPhone app (not necessarily Maps) or failing to do that just want to get coordinates to be copy/pasted to maps.

Preferred connection options are Bluetooth, wifi, and cable (in this order).

What would be a practical approach for this requirement? I've read about the iPhone location API not being reachable from BT. There are UART-capable WiFi chips, but I am not sure if it is possible to handle that on the phone side.

Perhaps a lightning -> serial cable allows me to see raw NMEA data, but I wanted to explore if you think of a better solution.

Comment: BLE and the location API are two different things. You’ll need to write an application to do what you require.